# Is the service affected when all masters are stopped?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, open-closed-principle, okd

Is the service affected when all masters are stopped?

OpenShift 4

- Infra Node 3
- Master Node 3
- Worker Node 3

※ Router pods are in the Infra Node.

The work request is as follows.

- frontend(DC) -> api(DC)

  - Internet -> Infra Node(Router) -> SDN -> Worker Node
- www.frontend.test.com(443) - Route

  - api REST Call (HttpUrlConnection or HttpClient 4.x, api:8080 or api.test1.svc.cluster.local:8080)

When all master nodes are stopped, the front-end always succeeds. However, the API call fails intermittently.

Slow Hang or UnknownHostException Message.

It is ok if there is at least one master node.

```
GET http://api.test1.svc.cluster.local:8080/ : java.net.UnknownHostException: api.test1.svc.cluster.local
or
GET http://api:8080/ : java.net.UnknownHostException: api
```

When slow Message.

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-2" #33 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=6.89ms elapsed=452.97s tid=0x00007fdb88f15800 nid=0xb3 runnable  [0x00007fdb34fc2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(java.base@11.0.14.1/Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(java.base@11.0.14.1/InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(java.base@11.0.14.1/InetAddress.java:1519)
    at java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(java.base@11.0.14.1/InetAddress.java:848)
    - locked <0x0000000782ff5be0> (a java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(java.base@11.0.14.1/InetAddress.java:1509)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(java.base@11.0.14.1/InetAddress.java:1368)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(java.base@11.0.14.1/InetAddress.java:1302)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at
```

thank you.

Comment: Which service?  How is your application set up for its distributed architecture?  What code produces the backtrace you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is affected. Here's what's happening when you stop all the master nodes.

1. The incoming traffic to the DC egress is being forwarded to the `Ingress` component of your Kubernetes/Openshift cluster. (Your `front-end`).
2. This is succeeding because the name resolution of `Ingress` is responsibility of your infrastructure, since `Ingress` interfacing is external to `Openshift`.
3. Once the traffic reaches the `Ingress` (`front-end` successfully reached), it needs to be forwarded now, to the `backend` service depending on the path in the request.
4. This cannot be done, since `Ingress` objects, by design, dynamically resolve `Service` DNS names into IP addresses in order to reach them inside the cluster. This is done, so that when services go down and come up and the IP address changes, `Ingress` doesn't need to be reconfigured since the DNS name stays consistent.
5. Here, the resolution fails, because your DNS system (probably `core-dns`) is supposed to be running on the `master` nodes, which it isn't, and this leads to `unresolved name` behavior.
6. Sometimes, it is possible that the `Ingress` has a local resolver cache entry which is valid and the request makes it to the `Service` and it gets a response. But this is highly unstable, since it is possible that this cache has been set with a auto-clean timeout and those entries are automatically purged after a while.

Comment: Thank you. Even if dns is on all nodes, including worker nodes?

Comment: Worker nodes do not have DNS pods running. DNS pods are part of the master nodes only. Worker nodes carry `kube-proxy`, `kubelet` and your overlay component like `flannel` or `calico`. Not the DNS.

Comment: There's a single DNS setup in the entire cluster, by design. This is run as a `Service`, exposing a `Deployment` of a certain replica size. You will have problems if you have multiple DNS setups in your cluster, obviously.

Comment: Thank you. Normally, oc get pod running on all nodes, so I understood that.